# SQL Server - Align value to all identic IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server

If have the following situation and do not even know where to start. So some input would be really appreciated.

It is important to know that the statement needs to beginn with SELECT.

I need to identify if a records has an entry in a category field. If it has, I need to assign that exact category to all columns matching the ID.

```
ID | Firstname | Lastname | category
--------------------------------------
01 | John | Smith | bike 
01 | John | Smith |  
01 | John | Smith |  
02 | Tobi | Miller |  
02 | Tobi | Miller | bike 
02 | Tobi | Miller |  
03 | Kelly | Schult | car 
03 | Kelly | Schult | car 
03 | Kelly | Schult | 


desired result:

ID | Firstname | Lastname | category
--------------------------------------
01 | John | Smith | bike 
01 | John | Smith | bike
01 | John | Smith | bike 
02 | Tobi | Miller | bike 
02 | Tobi | Miller | bike 
02 | Tobi | Miller | bike 
03 | Kelly | Schult | car 
03 | Kelly | Schult | car 
03 | Kelly | Schult | car
```

Comment: What are you going to do when you have two different category values for the same person? And what have you tried?

Comment: It will not happen that we have two different category value for same person. each person can have one category (or none). I do not know where to start do be honest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select id, firstname, lastname,
       max(category) over (partition by id) as category
from t;
```

If you actually want to store the value in the table . . . reconsider.  You should have a table that has exactly one row per `id`.  That row should store the category that you want.  You can use a `join` to get the value, rather than storing the same value in multiple rows.

Comment: Hi @gordon Linoff thanks for your answer. The "problem" I experienced with a join was that I was not able to define to always join the row that holds the value category. Thats why wanted to first give all rows the value category and afterwards make a join to have exactly one ID per row. But if there is a way to directly make a join and assure that always the row including a value would be joined, I think that would be the better solution.

Comment: meanwhile I can confirm, that the code above is working.